# VB.NET - ReDim "Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected."

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB and I'm currently updating to VB.net.

I have the error `Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.` on the `To` part of this line:

```
ReDim m_ctrCurrentPositions(0 To m_frmResize.Controls.Count -1)
```

Where `m_ctrCurrentPositions` is defined as:

```
Private m_ctrCurrentPositions As ControlPositionType
```

After a bit of reading, I imagine the error is to do with `(0 To Count-1)`, should the parameter just be `(Count-1)`? Or is the statement wrong?

Comment: Not sure about this but I seem to remember that **you can't use directly a property to redim an array**. So you should **use a temp variable** in between to stock your value and then assign it into your redim. The `ReDim(0 To n)` and `ReDim(n)` are indeed equivalent but you can use both without any issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order to alter the size of any array you must pass an INTEGER as the parameter.

The statement you are looking for, i believe, is :

```
ReDim m_ctrCurrentPositions(m_frmResize.Controls.Count-1)
```

Also, If you want to keep the values in the array then you will want to use the `Preserve` keyword.